# Gmail send mail laravel

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, smtp, gmail, sendmail

My log:

". Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials h18-20020ac25972000000b004fb87638fc4sm3330209lfp.19 - gsmtp
".

How can I configure gmail mail so that I can send mail? Technical mail for customer service in our system.

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=
MAIL_PORT=
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
OFFICE_MAIL_ADDRESS=

I read online articles, blogs. I changed the settings in my google account. I can't.

Answer (score 2):

update the following in .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=<Gmail address>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<Google App passwords>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

To Get Google App passwords

Login To https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords with your desired gmail accounts

and Genrate App passwords and use; Dont forgert to activate 2-Step Verification

Hope it helps you;

Comment: @JakubKmiecik  test it here https://www.gmass.co/smtp-test